# Rails - Showing custom forms based on which radio button is chosen

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use JS to show custom forms based on the radio button that's clicked. I have a collection of radio buttons (code below). So far the forms are hidden but when I click on the button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

View - radio button collection

```
 <%= form.collection_radio_buttons(:number, [["1", '1'] ,["2", '2'], ["3", '3'], ["4", "4"], ["5", "5"], ["6", "6"] ], :first, :last) do |b|  %>
 <%= b.label { b.radio_button + image_tag(b.text+'.png') } %> 
 <% end %>
```

View - JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][name="number"]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '1') {
      document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";

      }
      else if (this.value == '2') {
            document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

The forms

```
        <p id="one" class="one" style="">
          <%= form.text_area :body, class:'', style:"" %>
        </p>

        <p id="two" class="two" style="">
          <%= form.text_area :body, class:'', style:"" %>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using JavaScript to correctly hide the forms based on the code you provided. The problem, however, might be with the way your jQuery code is picking the radio buttons.

Try using `$('input[type=radio][name=number]')` to specifically choose radio buttons with the "name" property set to "number" rather than `$('[name=number]')`. Your code should become more particular as a result and refrain from selecting input fields with similar "name" characteristics.

The code is provided here:

```js
document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=number]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == '1') {
      document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (this.value == '2') {
      document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

Also, make sure that you have included the jQuery library in your application.

Comment: Hi Abhisek, thank you. It's not working, but I appreciate it.